# When loading JSON data into postgresql database, it only loads last object?

Tags: json, django, postgresql, fixtures

I am working on a Django project and I'm trying to load data into my PostgreSQL database through fixtures. I've read the documentation and followed the same format but for some reason, despite having several data, it will only show the last object when I try to view them in my database. I've even tried loading as yaml but still the same result. Here's an example:

```
  {
"model": "my_app.post",
"pk": null,
"fields": {
  "category": 5,
  "post_title": "Your Next Investment 0.21 Acres of Flat Vacant Land 30 mins",
  "description": "It’s time to turn up the heat on your next investment. 0.21 acres of flat vacant land in Colorado City, Colorado. Start building your dream home now. This land would be the perfect place to start. Imagine waking up to unobstructed views and enjoying the many benefits of outdoor living.",
  "date_created": "2022-04-03"
}  
  },
  {
    "model": "my_app.post",
    "pk": null,
    "fields": {
      "category": 5,
      "post_title": "$1,225 / 364ft2 - Patio/Balcony, Central Air, Tennis Court",
      "description": "Welcome home to Alta Living! Settle into one of our renovated studio, one, or two bedroom homes. If you are searching for a relaxing and inviting space, you're in luck! Every floorplan offers spacious living areas, vinyl plank wood flooring, fresh paint, updated fixtures, and a fully-equipped kitchen with quartz countertops, stainless steel appliances, and new cabinets. This is our furnished studio, one bathroom floorplan with 364 square feet of living space. Please call a member of our friendly leasing staff for more information!",
      "date_created": "2022-04-03"
    }  
  }
]
```

It was able to load my JSON file for the categories but not this file. If I try loading it again, it duplicates the last object. This is the message I get when I run manage.py loaddata:

```
Installed 10 object(s) from 1 fixture(s)
```

And while that is the number of objects I have, it only shows the last one?

Comment: It sounds like what is happening is it is looping through the json correctly.  However, it seems like what is happening is the data is being overwritten each time the loop is iterated over, leaving you with the last object in the loop.  What seems to be the problem is the PK is null.  What if you change the PK's in the fixtures file to 1 and 2 and run manage.py loaddata again?

Comment: Thank you, the PK being set to null was definitely the issue there. I set it to integers and that fixed the problem!